# how to access templatefield from code behind

Tags: asp.net, gridview

the reason why i am looking to update dynamic is because i am using objectdatasource and my objectdatasource have a collection of object and within that object i have another object that i wanted to access so for an example:

```
+Student
  ......
  ......
  ......
  -Courses
    .........
    .........
    Name
```

**Update end**

how do i bind templatefield from code-behind?

```
<asp:Gridview ID="gridview1" runat="Server">
<columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>                       
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>

</columns>
</asp:Gridview>
```

Comment: Do you have a List of Courses or just one Course in Student type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all define your key field in GridView control, just add net attribute to GridView markup: `datakeynames="StudentID"`.

You can use both event handler for GridView: RowDataBound or RowCreated. Just add one of this event handler and find there control that is placed in your ItemTemplate. Like here, for instance:

```
void ProductsGridView_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Retrieve the LinkButton control from the first column.
      Label someLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("someLabel");
      if (someLabel != null)
      {
          // Get Student index
          int StudentId = (int)GridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0];
          // Set the Label Text
          // Define here all the courses regarding to current student id              
          someLabel.Text = // 
      }
    }

  }
```

This example was gotten from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcreated.aspx)

Comment: it will not work because i have main object collection witin it i have another object that i want to access its property `+ Student withint Student i have Courses object` and i want to access that `course.name`

Comment: even if i define the key in my datakeynames will not work because as i have said that i have a custom object.. the correct way of doing is `MyClass obj = (MyClass)(e.Row.DataItem);`

i will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some code samples from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

These are in VB but you should be able to locate C# also :-)

If you follow this link and scroll down you will find a code sample:

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/624380-gridview-generated-programmatically

Comment: Consider using a master-details to split this up.